# How to check table columns in dbml before executing query in Linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am having one window application which we will run on different systems to update database. 
Suppose we have 10 systems. Out of 10 systems 2 systems are using latest application with latest DBML. In latest DBML I have added columns in tables. For these systems everything working good.

**Problem :**

When I try to run it on old systems where I am using old database. When I run application it throws an error

> columns not found

Reason behind this is DBML is updated but database is not updated.

How can I handle this situation? I cannot update the database due to some restrictions.

Comment: do you want update the data without updating the database in older systems?

Comment: Yes. Because for old systems we will not provide values for these new columns.

Comment: Does every system  have its own database?

Comment: Yes, They have their own..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I am using the following steps :

1.Added one more DBML in project in other namespace than older DBML.Here i drop table with old schema.

2.Get columns of table as follow :

```
 class CheckVersion
{
    public static bool isOldSystem;
    public static void CheckColumnsInMasterInventory()
    {
        string[] Columns = { "Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4" };//New Columns Which are not present in Old table.
        List<string> ColumnList = new List<string>();
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var schemaCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (var reader = schemaCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(reader);
                    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        ColumnList.Add(column.ColumnName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var columnCount = ColumnList.Where(item => Columns.Contains(item)).Count();
        if (columnCount == 4)
            isOldSystem = false;
        else
            isOldSystem = true;
    }
}
```

3.On the Basis of

```
isOldSystem
```

value i am executing linq as follow :

```
  DataLoaderDataContext objDC = new DataLoaderDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        DataLoaderOldDataContext objOldDC = new DataLoaderOldDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            if (!CheckVersion.isOldSystem)
            {
                //objDC
            }
            else
            {
               //objOldDC
            }
```

Now i am able to handle Old as well as New Database.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case you should [version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) your code. The dbml that you are using should reflect the schema of the database and in your case it doesn't happens.

So I suggest you two version of your application each one with dbml updated with the database.

1. So your application version 1.1 will contain older dbml
2. Version 1.2 is the actual version with updated dbml

**update**

So my answer is **No** you can't do something like this because the dbml (that doesn't reflect the database) thinks that columns all exist.

So you can try checking this columns with a standard `SqlCommand` and do a query directly to the database.

Comment: :-) faby this was first strike in my mind but we have to use only one version.

Comment: I can't see other solution because you should not have dbml different from database. You should try to edit run time the dbml and I think it's not a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

It might be an option to create updateable views. I do know you can add views to the DBML.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

In theory, this could work. But I have to admit I never tried this in real life.

How to do it, is answered overhere at SO:
[LINQ to SQL : How to Insert record into a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796831/linq-to-sql-how-to-insert-record-into-a-view)